# Split a sentence in array of string with special characters or spaces intact

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split a sentence having spaces or any special character into an array of words with spaces or special character also an element of array.

Sentence like:

```
aman,amit and sumit went to top-up
```

should be split into an array of String:

```
{"aman",",","amit"," ","and"," ","sumit"," ","went"," ","to"," ","top","-","up")
```

Please suggest any regex or logic to split the same using java.

I missed one thing in my question. I also need to split on numeric character as well.. But using split("\b") does not split a string having something like

> abc12def

into

```
{ "abc", "12","def") or {"abc","1","2","def")
```

Comment: You can use `.split("\\b")`

Comment: Sorry but can we see [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far and what problem you are facing?

Comment: Also what about continues spaces? Should them be separated like `"foo  bar"` (there are two spaces between foo and bar) -> `["foo", " ", " ", "bar"]` or you want to have them as one token `["foo", "  ", "bar"]`?

Comment: I wanted to keep the spaces as is.. 
Solution provided by @4castle works for me. Thanks

Comment: Another one - http://ideone.com/yvdvU4

Comment: I missed one thing in my question. I also need to split on numeric character as well.. But using split("\\b") does not split a string having something like abc12def into  { "abc", "12","def") or {"abc","1","2","def").

Answer (score 0):

It seems all you need is to match either word characters (`\w+`) or non-word ones (`\W+`). Combine these with an alternation operator and - perhaps - add a `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` (or its inline/embedded version `(?U)`) to make the pattern Unicode-aware:

```
String value = "aman,amit and sumit went to top-up";
String pattern = "(?U)\\w+|\\W+";
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
while (m.find())
    lst.add(m.group(0));
System.out.println(lst);
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/yvdvU4)

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below code snippet helps you solve this.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
        String message = "aman,amit and sumit went to top-up";
        String[] messages = message.split("\\b");
        for(String string : messages) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
```